# Trying to reset password but I don't know my Player ID - how do I get this?

Tags: pokemon-go

When I got my reset password email I follow the link to reset. But at the bottom one of the fields required is "PLAYER ID" so I can't reset/play.

What do I do? Where do I get this value from?

Answer (score 3):

The Pokemon trainer club website needs date of birth and player id that you entered when you created the account.  The player id is set when you use the Play! Pokemon program.  If you have not done so, the field should be left blank; if you have, the ID is a 7 digit number that was given you when you set up the Play! account.

If you can still login to the PTC website, you can view your profile and select play! on the list to see your player id; if you can't, you'll need to contact support and explain the situation.  email is techhelp@pokemon.com